# Elastic Beanstalk: Can't read file pulled from S3 within node.js application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using an .ebextensions file to initialize my system and pull some .pem files from my S3 bucket. However, I constantly get access denied errors when trying to read this file within my node.js application. I've confirmed the contents of the file pulled from S3 are correct.

Is there an issue my configuration file?

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/certificates/cert.pem":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: nodejs
    group: users
    source: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/folder/cert.pem"

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: myBucket
```

Error given by node.js:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/ec2-user/certificates/cert.pem'
```

Comment: Did you try to login into the machine and access the S3 file manully to check permissions?

Comment: Yes and the permissions are as expected. I've installed nvm on this machine for testing and was able to use the fs module to read it just fine. My node.js application has no such luck however.

Answer (score 1):

Your node.js application user, nodejs, is not allowed to download a file into the ec2-user home directory.  You can instead download the file to the `/tmp` directory, and then move it using a container command. The container commands are executed from the root of the staged application right before it is deployed.

```
files:
  "/tmp/cert.pem":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: nodejs
    group: users
    source: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/folder/cert.pem"

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: myBucket

container_commands:
  file_transfer_1:
    command: "mkdir -p certificates"
  file_transfer_2:
    command: "mv /tmp/cert.pem certificates/."
```